# Metanalysis in R for writing interventions

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I do a metanalysis (the subject is writing interventions for students with Learning Disabilities) in R package. Due to the use of continuous variables, the effect size I used was the Standardized Mean Difference. For the averages of the experimental group and the control group and the corresponding standard deviations I used the performance of the post tests. Considering that the effect sizes between the studies would be very different I used the random effects model. But i have one question:
One of my research question is:  ''Do programs balancing reading and writing instruction improve better students writing performance rather than programs focusing only in writing instruction?''. Ι found that the effect size of writing interventions was 1.10 and for programs balancing reading and writing instruction was 0.52. Do i need to run and meta regression for this research question or is that enough? I have only 5-6 studies that calculate reading comprehension.